# Move popup when device's (android) keyboard is active

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I would like to move the popup, when keyboard is active, because right now keyboard covers the popup. How can I know sizes of keyboard to properly move popup?

```
Popup {
    id: popupName
    contentWidth: parent.width/2
    contentHeight: parent.height/2

    x: parent.width/2 - popupName.width/2
    y: parent.height/2 - popupName.height/2

    background: Rectangle {
        color: "#424242"
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [`Qt.inputMethod.keyboardRectangle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#inputMethod-prop):

> The inputMethod object allows access to application's QInputMethod object and all its properties and slots. See the QInputMethod documentation for further details.

The [docs for `QInputMethod`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#keyboardRectangle-prop) say:

> This property holds virtual keyboard's geometry in window coordinates.
>
> This might be an empty rectangle if it is not possible to know the geometry of the keyboard. This is the case for a floating keyboard on android.

I'm not sure if the keyboard in your screenshot is considered a "floating keyboard" or not.

Comment: It's not, a keyboard is floating when it's not docked to the bottom of the screen, like this : http://i.imgur.com/E4xBDTY.png